# Excel formula change to m/d/y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What formula should I try to use to convert date:

> Cell **A1 = 01/07/2018 00:02:05**

to

> **07/01/2018**

Comment: Use text to columns with one column and chose date.

Comment: If you want it to remain a date you could use `=DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),DAY($A$1))` but easier just to reformat the cell to `dd/mm/yyyy`.  If the custom format doesn't work then, as @ImaginaryHuman072889 said, your original value is not a format that Excel recognises as a date.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just change the date format of the cell `Format > Date` and find that format, or enter `mm/dd/yyyy` as a custom format. If you absolutely must use a formula then use `TEXT()` like so:

`=TEXT(DATE(2018,7,1),"mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: I tried to enter mm/dd/yyyy as custom format, but it didn't work

Comment: @user10157627 Then your cell is not formatted as a date that Excel recognizes.